# Running commands upon creation of instances using AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been looking at various methods to run commands upon creation of EC2 instances using Elastic Beanstalk on AWS. I've been given different methods to do this through AWS Tech Support, including life cycle hooks, custom AMI's, and .ebextensions. I've been having issues getting the first 2 methods (life cycle hooks and custom AMIs) to work with EB.

I'm currently using .ebextensions to run commands upon deploy, but not sure if there's a way to run a set of commands upon creation only instead of every time I deploy code. For instance, I have a file `.ebextensions/03-commands.config` that contains the following code:

```
container_commands:
  01_npm_install:
    command: "npm install -g -f npm@latest"
```

However, I only want this code to run upon instance creation, not every time I deploy, as it currently does. Does anyone know a way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May add more details what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @VadymFedorov I've modified a bit to include more information. Does this help?

Comment: I have found great success using both method 1 and 2 suggested by AWS Tech Support. Life cycle hooks are great for one off command execution (i.e. on instance creation like you want) so I suggesting researching into it a bit more. Custom AMIs are wonderful for more advanced configuration needs (i.e. installing a lot of custom software, updating it, setting up the environment, etc.). Give them a try again, and come back if you continue to have difficulties!

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend creating an idempotent script in your application that leaves a marker file on the instance in some location say /var/myapp/marker using something like `mkdir -p /var/myapp-state/; touch /var/myapp-state/marker` on successful execution. That way in your script you can check that if the marker file exists you can make your script a no-op.

Then you can call your script from container commands but it will be a no-op everytime because on first successful execution it will create the marker file and subsequent executions will be no-ops.

Comment: Who knows why some people downvote? I balanced it for you, as it seemed like a sensible solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom AMI. This way you can setup your instances whoever you want and they will launch faster

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html

Comment: I didn't downvote however custom ami's can cause a lot of headaches and you have to maintain them, much better to use ebextensions and the default elastic beanstalk ami where ever possible

Comment: If you do a lot of scaling (or for other reason needs to launch quickly) and has a complex setup with rpms and other things that takes time you can take that out that step completely. Managing ami's are not hard and can be fiarly easy be done through automation.

Answer (score 0):

As I see from you question, you're using: container_commands, that is means you are using Elastic Beanstalk with Docker. Right? In this case I would recommended to read: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html.

The idea is following, that you can create own Dockerfile, where you can specify all commands that you need to build a docker container, for example to install all dependencies.

I would recommended to use .ebextensions for the Elastic Beanstalk customization and configuration, for example to specify ELB or RDS configuration. In the Dockerfile make sense to specify all commands, that you need to build a container for your application, that includes setup of the web server, dependencies etc.

With this approach, Elastic Beanstalk will build a container, that each time when you do deploy, it execute a docker instance with deployed source code.

Comment: container_commands has nothing to do with Docker when using Elastic Beanstalk. These are the commands that run in the virtual environment on your Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance. commands run on your EC2 instance.

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple option **leader_only: true** you need to use as per current AWS Elasticbeanstalk configurations, You simply need to add this under

```
container_commands:
  01_npm_install:
    command: "npm install -g -f npm@latest"
    leader_only: true
```

This is the link as per AWS
[AWS Elasticbeanstalk container command option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands)

Comment: leader_only is used to specify that the command is only to be run on one of the instances in a load-balanced setup.  It does not pertain to the question of whether the command runs on instance creation or upon every deployment.